# Getting error: Launch configuration XXX.XML.settingDropDown.xml references non-existing project FlockHydra-Automation

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I have cloned an existing project from github. On trying to open the project in Eclipse, it gets imports as a Maven project.

When I try to run an XML file, it shows me the following error. Did a bit of research but couldn't find a proper solution to this.

[image: Error in Eclipse]

Comment: I can't see your error - provide it in text

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the guides on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @rudolf_franek Launch configuration FlockHydra-Automation_FlockHydraAutomation.XML.settingDropDown.xml references non-existing project FlockHydra-Automation.